# `keepdims` changes output value

Tags: python, numpy

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2)
x = np.random.randn(1000000).astype('float32')
print(float(np.linalg.norm(x, keepdims=1)**2))
print(float(np.linalg.norm(x, keepdims=0)**2))
```

```
998428.125
998428.1084311157
```

Reproduced in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com). Also, Colab outputs different values than my CPU:

```
998425.0625
998425.059075091
```

Removing `**2`, they match. Also reproduced with `sum`, haven't tried other methods.

Why this behavior? I can understand device dependence but `keepdims` seems buggy.

Comment: Looks like you're at the precision limit for floats. Values agree to 7 decimal places

Comment: The dupe is not exact, but you asked it and I was about to answer something very similar... the same thing is probably happening: value-based type promotion differs between scalars and 1-element 1d arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because after `keepdims=0`, your NumPy turns into a single dim float32, which after `**2`, becomes a float64. The other still has two axes and for some reason NumPy does not do this.

```py
>>> print(
>>>    np.linalg.norm(x, keepdims=1).dtype, 
>>>    np.linalg.norm(x, keepdims=0).dtype
>>> )
# Returns

float32 float32

>>> print(
>>>   (np.linalg.norm(x, keepdims=1)**2).dtype, 
>>>   (np.linalg.norm(x, keepdims=0) ** 2).dtype
>>> )
# Returns
float32 float64
```

The version of numpy I'm using is `1.20.3`.

I could not find any documentation of why this happens in the NumPy documentation. I think opening a GitHub issue in [NumPy's repository](https://github.com/numpy/numpy), might be a good idea.

Comment: Reasonable, though unclear where it's cast exactly: applying `.astype('float32')` on both yields same outputs, but not `.astype('float64')` (e.g. `(norm(x, keepdims=0) ** 2).astype`).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon It might be that the power operation on single element (with shape ()) is fully done in the float64 mode (first casts the array to float64 and then does the power of 2 operation), while the other is done in native float32. After recasting them there will be mismatch because of the loss of precision. If you first cast them to float64, the only difference will be in how the input is truncated in `__repr__` and string representation of array, while the  result of `float(arr)` of both will be the same.